# How to compare strings with special characters in PHP?

Tags: php, string, compare

I have two strings

```
$string1 = 'Amateur developer | Photoshop lover| Alcohol scholar |  Internet practitioner';
```

and

```
$string2 = 'Amateur developer | Photoshop lover| Alcohol scholar';
```

How to compare these two strings in `PHP` with special characters (spaces and hyphens) in between?

Comment: Please be more specific in what exactly you want. You can certainly compare two strings with those characters using the usual operators.

Comment: As your questions stands... `if($string1===$string2) {}`

Comment: You could try creating an array using explode, then comparing using Jaccard Index

Comment: @ElonThan oops, Naughty Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for compare with Case;

```
  $result = strcmp($string1, $string2);
```

Try this for compare without Case to consier;

```
  $result = strcasecmp($string1, $string2);
```

if $result is 0(zero) then strings are equal otherwise not in both case.

Comment: I don't know the reason why some-one down-vote this answer???
What is wrong with this answer??? Please Explain in brief.

Comment: Your effort is good, but your answer isn't appropriate, someone down voted because your answer can only compare strings without special characters in it. User wants to compare strings with special characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = strcmp($string1, $string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Jaccard Index, see this: https://gist.github.com/henriquea/540303

```
<?php

function getSimilarityCoefficient( $item1, $item2, $separator = "," ) {

    $item1 = explode( $separator, $item1 );
    $item2 = explode( $separator, $item2 );
    $arr_intersection = array_intersect( $item2, $item2 );
    $arr_union = array_merge( $item1, $item2 );
    $coefficient = count( $arr_intersection ) / count( $arr_union );

    return $coefficient;
}

$string2 = 'Amateur developer | Photoshop lover | Alcohol scholar |  Internet practitioner';
$string2 = 'Amateur developer | Photoshop lover | Alcohol scholar';

echo getSimilarityCoefficient($string1,$string2,' | ');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're consistently split by a pipe (`|`) and you just want a down and dirty check:

```
// original strings
$str1 = 'Amateur developer | Photoshop lover| Alcohol scholar |  Internet practitioner';
$str2 = 'Amateur developer | Photoshop lover| Alcohol scholar';

// split them by the pipe
$exp1 = explode('|', $str1);
$exp2 = explode('|', $str2);

// trim() them to remove excess whitespace
$trim1 = array_map('trim', $exp1);
$trim2 = array_map('trim', $exp2);

// you could also array_map them to strtolower
// to take CaSE out of the equation
```

Then:

```
// MATCHING ENTRIES

$same = array_intersect($trim1, $trim2);
var_dump($same);

// DIFFERENT ENTRIES
$diff = array_diff($trim1, $trim2);
var_dump($diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This similar_text() - Calculate the similarity between two strings

Answer (score 0):

**Looking for this kind of comparison ?**

```
<?php

$string1 = 'Amateur developer | Photoshop lover| Alcohol scholar |  Internet practitioner';

$string2 = 'Amateur developer | Photoshop lover| Alcohol scholar';

if ($string1 == $string2) {

  echo "Strings are same";
} else {

  $stringArray1 = explode(' | ', $string1);
  $stringArray2 = explode(' | ', $string2);

  $diffAre = array_diff($stringArray1, $stringArray2);
  echo "Difference in strings are " . implode($diffAre, ',');
}
?>
```

**Output**

```
Difference in strings are Internet practitioner
```